# Is there a way to get two *mut pointers pointing to the same memory address?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a Doubly Linked List for fun in Rust.

I faced an issue with the ownership system, the inability to alias two pointers. I realize the benefits of pointer aliasing, but I'd like to make an exception this time.

I'd like to know if there is any way to have two `*mut A` pointers pointing to the same memory address.

For example, right now I have this:

```rust
self.first = unsafe { mem::transmute(new_node) };
// How do I set self.last to point at the same new_node?
```

I am aware of `Rc` and `RefCell` types, but I'd like to avoid using them in data structures as they have run-time overhead.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context (e.g. definition of the `self` struct)? It will help tailor the answers to make the most sense.

Comment: `*mut` or `&mut`? The former has no aliasing requirements AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with dbaupp that you should provide more context because this isn't what you should do, here's the answer to the exact question you asked:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: u32 = 42;
    let b: *mut u32 = &mut a;
    let c: *mut u32 = &mut a;
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", b, c);
}
```

Now you have two `*mut u32` pointers pointing at the same memory address. And without `unsafe`! Of course, if you want to *use* the pointers, you now have to do a lot more thinking to decide if you've completely broken all the assumptions and guarantees that the compiler expects! :-)

Comment: Ah right I can just reference multiple times and then cast them. Thanks this should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean. `&mut` is the one that has the aliasing enforcing. `*mut` can be copied like anything else, dereferencing a raw pointer of course is `unsafe`, but you should be able to do this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: i32 = 5i32;
    let xptr: *mut i32 = &mut x as *mut i32;

    let xptr_copy: *mut i32 = xptr;

    unsafe {
        println!("xptr: {}", *xptr);
        println!("xptr_copy: {}", *xptr_copy);
    }
}
```

[playpen](http://is.gd/Zhhb8P)